# Switching tabs in Firefox + Firebug is very, very slow

Tags: firefox, memory-leaks, firebug

I'm experiencing a huge memory consumption using Firebug after the Firefox update to Version 24.
Firefox freezes for up to 30 seconds if I am trying to switch to another Tab while Firebug is enabled.

Disableing Firebug is solving the issue, but that is not a solution to me.

Is there a workarround?

Answer (score 3):

The described behavour is a known Bug, Sebastian Zartner answerd on [GGroups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebug/X7-L4fTuM1Y/kUrzySeEMuEJ):

> This problem is caused by the debugger API Firebug uses. We're working hard on [switching to a new debugger API](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5421), which should solve problems like this.
>   There's also a [related report at Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=815603) to improve the performance of the old debugging API.

But most developers can't wait for the new debugger API nor work with having Firebug disabled completly, so try the following solution instead:

1. Activate Firebug
2. Go to the **Script** tab inside of Firebug
3. **Disable** it, feel better.

[image: how to disable Scripts]

Disabling the scripts will avoid the memory leak without having Firebug disabled completly.